# Regarding checkboxes in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a web page and in it I have a checkbox at the top of the page and another checkbox at the bottom of the page. Now my problem is if I check the top checkbox the bottom checkbox also need to be checked and if I uncheck the bottom checkbox the top checkbox need to be unchecked.
The functionality of the two checkboxes must be the same.
This must be need to solved by Jquery.

Comment: what are you doing puja? Can you paste your code here?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Give this a go

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function(){$("input[type=checkbox]").attr("checked",$(this).attr("checked"));}
})
```

Comment: it will affect ANY input on the page

Comment: This is wrong, checkbox value will not give you state of checkbox. "Checked" is parameter for input, same as "value" is parameter.

Comment: Geez... Stop being a negative nancy

Comment: I got once -4 for wrong answer (before I removed it), as I did not checked what I was answering, that was good lesson for me. I hope, this will be for you too ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how we can restrict the function only for the required two checkboxes.

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".checkBoxClass").click(function () {
          $(".checkBoxClass").attr("checked",$(this).attr("checked"));
     });
});
</script>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" value="" />Top<br/>

<input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" value="" />Bottom
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is problem, to read jQuery documentation? :thumbsdown: for such an easy question...

Select all checkboxes or a specific one:

```
var chkbx = $('input[type=checkbox]');
```

Know, if it's checked:

```
chkbx.is(':checked');
```

Check it, if needed:

```
chkbx.attr('checked', true);
```

Or uncheck:

```
chkbx.attr('checked', false);
```

Change state of all checkboxes simultaniously (if you select specific ones by modifying select statement, you will get what you needed):

```
chkbx.change(function(){
$('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', $(this).is(':checked'))
});
```

I hope, this is enough for you, to solve your case.

Comment: @puja, You mean, very far from jQuery? :P

Comment: @puja, additionally, if you like any of given answers, use Check mark to the left of it, to reward answerer for his spent time on question :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).attr('checked');
    $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
        $(this).attr('checked', val);
    });
});
```